# ¿Cómo puedo pasar una variable de php a Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un inicio de sesión, de forma local y con redes sociales, cuando el usuario está logueado se le muestra su nombre. Cuando llamo el nombre para el usuario local lo hago así `print ($_SESSION['cNombreUsuario']);` y cuando llamo el nombre para el usuario con redes sociales lo hago así `print_r($_SESSION['user']['cNombreUsuario']);`.

Cuando el usuario está logueado de forma local le puse el siguiente parámetro a la url: `index.php?local` para identificar.

Mi problema es que no encuentro cómo llamar las variables que puse anteriormente a javascript.

Código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var local = document.location.href;
    var getStringL = local.split('?')[1];
    if (getStringL == "local"){
        var getStringL = <?php print ($_SESSION['cNombreUsuario']); ?>

    }else{

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Solo cómo comentario hacer lo que pides es considerado una mala práctica, lo ideal sería que por medio de un endpoint accedas a la información que necesitas, sin embargo me parece que la respuesta de @jmrtn es correcta

Comment: @learnercys Perdona mi pregunta, pero cómo puedo utilizar endpoint para acceder a la información. Y por qué es una mala práctica... estoy comenzando a aprender por eso soy novata aún :)

Comment: Es una mala práctica, no debes mezclar lógica de negocio con vistas por más que te sientas tentado a hacerlo, si haces esto habitualmente cuando realices aplicaciones más complejas tendrás un código de poca calidad e incapaz de escalar. Te recomiendo seguir los principios [SOLID](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). Lo natural en una aplicación web es pedirle al servidor los datos que necesitemos y, eso se hace mediante un sistema de rutas o mediante una API.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Muchas gracias por el comentario, investigué sobre el sistema de rutas y me funcionó. 
Investigaré más sobre SOLID

Answer (score 3):

La única manera segura de pasar un valor de PHP a javascript en tiempo de generación del HTML es haciendo uso de [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var local = document.location.href;
  var getStringL = local.split('?')[1];
  if (getStringL == "local") {
    var getStringL = <?= json_encode($_SESSION['cNombreUsuario']) ?>;
  } else {
  }
</script>
```

La función `json_encode()` decidirá la forma en la que mostrará el contenido de la variable atendiendo al tipo de datos que contiene. Si `$_SESSION['cNombreUsuario']` es una cadena, `json_encode` agregará las comillas y escapará correctamente su contenido. Si fuera una matriz, usará la notación javascript necesaria para crear la misma matriz en javascript y lo mismo con clases y otros tipos de datos (obviamente los recursos de PHP no funcionarán como esperas).

[JSON](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) es la notación de datos que tiene Javascript.

Comment: Excepto para números, en donde no habría problema con imprimirlos directamente.

Comment: Si estás seguro del contenido de la variable, sí, pero sin conocer qué contenido podría tener lo más seguro es usar `json_encode` y que PHP decida qué manera debe usar para plasmar el contenido en javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Pones una etiqueta PHP dentro de javascript.

```
<?php
$TuVariablePHP;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var TuVariableJS = "<?php echo '$TuVariablePHP;' ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: usa el print corto:  <?=@$TuVariablePHP?>

Comment: Con comillas simples en PHP, el resultado de ese `echo` no va a ser el esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo la respuesta de @IrvingNgr, queria aclarar que eso solo se puede hacer si estás en un mismo archivo.

El ejemplo que el muestra no me funcionó, yo lo hice de esta manera.

```
let variable = '<?php echo $variable_2; ?>';
```

El problema era con las comillas. Si se las agrega a $variable_2, no la detecta como variable.